# Component is not getting renderend properly with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
 function App() {
  return (
    //BEM naming convention
    <div className="app">
      <div className="app__body">
        <Sidebar />
        <Chat />
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/arroz" element={<MainPage />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

can someone explain me why when i inicialize app, its rendering as supposed to and when i try to render the same thing but with the components inside this one component, it looses the css i have done and only uses a small part of screen. also when i render the page, it should only render the component, but instead is also rendering code that shouldnt be read.

[how its being rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs072.png)

[how it should be rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOVDn.png)

```
import React from "react";
import Chat from "./Chat";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";

function MainPage() {
  return (
    <div className="mainPage">
      <Sidebar />
      <Chat />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainPage;
```

obs: i didnt styled MainPage.css and as i was inspecting the page the compenent had "display:block" dont know the meaning

i have done this and this works as i want, still i would like to understand why is not taking the form its suposed to

```
function App() {
  return (
    //BEM naming convention
    <div className="app">
      <div className="app__body">
        <Sidebar />

        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/rooms/:roomId" element={<Chat />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you ***not*** wanting to render two `Chat` and `Sidebar` components? I don't think CSS has anything to do with rendering these components in two places.

Comment: yes i am, but the thing here is why they geting deformed

Comment: Ok, maybe the CSS ***is*** relevant then? Can you add the CSS you are using and any other code that may be relevant? See [mcve]. Think you could also create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-architecture-fnslvj                 i never used this

Comment: Sorry, I meant for the sandbox to also be a minimal code example to reproduce the issue. It's effectively a code dump and doesn't have the code changes you are asking about in your question here.

Comment: in there i put the older version i had from my project, without the routers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

it seems if i put this on indeex and change the app like this it works has it suposed to

```
function App() {
  return (
    //BEM naming convention
    <div className="app">
      <div className="app__body">
        <Sidebar />

        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/rooms/:roomId" element={<Chat />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```